# Cake PHP Session issue with Email Component

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am passing through very strange issue with Cakephp session. Session is working if I am not including Email code in controller. And Session will set and it will available in View.

```
$this->Email->to = 'email@example.com';
$this->Email->subject = 'Website request';
$this->Email->send($this->data['Contact']['message']);
$this->Session->write('success','After Sending Email.');
// This will not save session.
```

But If I include Email code and set the session it will not set session and also will not be available in View.

```
//$this->Email->to = 'email@example.com';
//$this->Email->subject = 'Website request';
//$this->Email->send($this->data['Contact']['message']);
$this->Session->write('success','After Sending Email.');
// This will save session as email code is commented
```

Now the real problem comes. When I set session before sending email it will be available in view but if I set session after sending email, it is not available in view file. Please check below code block for the same.

```
$this->Session->write('success','After Sending Email.');
$this->Email->to = 'email@example.com';
$this->Email->subject = 'Website request';
$this->Email->send($this->data['Contact']['message']);
// This will save session as its set before sending email
```

could some one please figure out what is going wrong with My Code or CakePHP??

Comment: I would expect your email sending to fail and throw an exception. That is the only scenario that would explain the behavior. Does it do that? Or does it continue without any error, notice or exception thrown?

Comment: its continue execution and no exception or error at all.

Comment: I am not getting any error as email is sending successfully.